# Excel: SUMIF column A = x and (y or z)

Tags: arrays, if-statement, filter, excel-formula, sumifs

Here is an example of the data I am using.

```
0 |      A      |    B
1 | Information |   Time  
2 | ----------- | ---------
3 |   x y abc   |    3
4 |   x z abc   |    4
5 |   y z abc   |    5
```

I would expect this to return the value 7.

I understand SUMIF(B:B,A:A,"*x*") and using SUMIF for multiple criteria but I am struggling to figure out how to integrate the ability for an and/or SUMIF.

DATA TABLE

```
50e flute dolley tripped twice          |   0.29
dolly tripped paser flute               |   0.21
No 5 tripeed. Waiting for sparky.       |   0.18
No 2 tripped - waiting for sparky.      |   0.14
No 2 dolly tripped - waiting for sparky |   0.09
Dolly tripped, waiting for sparky       |   0.08
No 2 dolly - waiting for sparky         |   0.08
50e flute dolly                         |   0.07
dolly tripped 50e flute                 |   0.06
no 2 dolley tripped                     |   0.06
50e flute dolley (side 1) tripped       |   0.06
No 2 - waiting for sparky               |   0.06
```

I want 5 different functions for the 5 different reel dollies. So for number 5, I want to ensure I am only counting the no 5 dolly and not the 50e flute dolly. This is a dataset entered external so I want to be able to cover criteria that includes wrongly spelled words and multiple names for a particular reel dolly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A, "*x*",A:A, {"*y*","*z*"}))
```

Which means to sum column B *where A contains "x" and either of "y" and "z".

The logic in this construction is:

- mandatory criteria come alone
- "ORed" criteria come inside the `{...}` array.

Example, dolley no 2:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A, "* 2 *",A:A, {"*dolly*","*dolley*", "no *"}))
```

Comment: I have added my data set to be more precise as requested.

Comment: @Danny still not completely clear. Would you show on the example data, which rows should be included in the sum?

Comment: It would include the entire columns as it can be of varying sizes. therefore B:B would be the some range, and A:A would be the criteria range. Is that clear?

Comment: Also a further point: In order to set up criteria to sum the time for reel dolly number 2, it would require '2' and 'no or dolly or dolley etc'. The sum for this data set should then equal 0.43 using 0.14 + 0.09 + 0.08 + 0.06 + 0.06

Comment: @Danny then something like `=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A, " 2 ",A:A, {"*dolly*","*dolley*", "no *"}))`... You see the logic: mandatory criteria come alone, `OR`ed criteria inside `{...}` array.

Comment: I've noticed this only identifies when the words come in the correct order, is there any way to use the criteria regardless of the word order within the text cell?

Comment: @Danny it's not at all sensitive to the order, but only the fact that "* 2 *" wont match if the number 2 comes at the beginning of the sentence. If that occurs and is the problem it might need some further tweaking.

Comment: To solve this specific issue try `=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A, {"* 2 *";"2 *"},A:A, {"*dolly*","*dolley*","no *"}))`

Comment: Using this gives me a result of 0.47 which doesn't make sense even though it is clearly picking up results.

Comment: @Danny hmmm.. yes it's vexing. It's because there are rows that simultaneously match more than one of the grouped criteria, so they will be counted twice. I think we should give up on `SUMIFS` on this one and try arrays with `SUMPRODUCT`, or something similar.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and see what I can come up with.

Comment: After playing around with 'SUMIFS' I've noticed the function is actually counting rows that meet both criteria twice when it returns a larger number.

Answer (score 0):

I try to find any exact formula, but unable to find the same, we have some other trick by which you can do the same.

```
=(SUM(SUMIFS(D2:D11,A2:A11,"South", C2:C11,"Meat"),SUMIFS(D2:D11,A2:A11,"South", C2:C11,"Beverages")))
```

or

```
=(SUMIFS(D2:D11,A2:A11,"South", C2:C11,"Meat")+SUMIFS(D2:D11,A2:A11,"South", C2:C11,"Beverages"))
```

Hopefully this will help

Comment: Thank you for your help, please can you explain what these functions do?

Comment: As per your query SUMIFS will add the value based on conditon (And condtion SUMIFS(D2:D11,A2:A11,"South", C2:C11,"Meat") means, this will give some of column from D2-->D11 with two condition one is A2-->A11 is South and second condition C2-->C11 is Meat, This is and condition example, because we don't have or condition so we can use two SumIFs and add the value of both two achieve or condition like below =(SUMIFS(D2:D11,A2:A11,"South", C2:C11,"Meat")+SUMIFS(D2:D11,A2:A11,"South", C2:C11,"Beverages")) , It will give result for South with Meat or South with Beverages, I hope this will help you

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I would like to see what A.S.H gives before I choose an answer :)

Comment: For my situation I am only using 2 columns where all the text is within one cell.
I've noticed this only identifies when the words come in the correct order, is there any way to use the criteria regardless of the word order within the text cell?